# 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1105: cannot close file

Tags: c++, directx-11

I use MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, and I can run a project once and it will work perfectly. If I then make any type of change whatsoever to the program, and then try to build then I get the following error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1105: cannot close file 'F:\C++ Projects\Rastertek Projects\Engine\Debug\Engine.exe'

Restarting my computer fixes the error, but only for 1 instance of running the program. I already deleted 1GB worth of files off of the 4GB USB flash drive I do all of my programming on, and it still produces the error. This is a fairly recent problem of mine, as I could work on programs in the past with no issues.

Comment: Your program doesn't close properly. Make it close properly.

Comment: All objects are being released and set to 0. The only thing I can think to change would be setting them to nullptr.

Comment: I'm not talking about those; I'm talking about your program not closing properly. It hangs on an infinite loop or something like that.

Comment: I'll have to check for that. My other DirectX program I'm working on doesn't have this issue, but following the Rastertek tutorials to the T produces the issue. I saw someone say they were of low quality aside from using OOP techniques.

Comment: It's a line of code you've written. Of course, we cannot guess what that code says! You'll have to present a [MCVE].

Comment: I have reposted the question with just windows code at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151328/1link-fatal-error-lnk1105-cannot-close-file-oop-approach

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file and run it before building:

```
taskkill /im engine.exe /f
```

Comment: Unfortunately that method doesn't work for some reason. I tried multiple times and tried including the full location too.